# Calculate an IPv6 range from a CIDR prefix?

Tags: php, ipv6, cidr

I am able to do this with IPv4 using code snippets from various online sources. I was wondering if there was a way to do it with IPv6.

Basically I just need a form that I can enter an IPv6 address and prefix (ex: f080:42d2:581a::0/68) and it calculates the network address, first useable address, last useable address, and broadcast address. Then just prints to screen. Not looking to store it in a database or anything yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all: IPv6 doesn't have network and broadcast addresses. You can use all addresses in a prefix. Second: On a LAN the prefix length is always (well, 99.x% of the time) a /64. Routing a /68 would break IPv6 features like stateless auto configuration.

Below is a verbose implementation of an IPv6 prefix calculator:

```
<?php

/*
 * This is definitely not the fastest way to do it!
 */

// An example prefix
$prefix = '2001:db8:abc:1400::/54';

// Split in address and prefix length
list($firstaddrstr, $prefixlen) = explode('/', $prefix);

// Parse the address into a binary string
$firstaddrbin = inet_pton($firstaddrstr);

// Convert the binary string to a string with hexadecimal characters
# unpack() can be replaced with bin2hex()
# unpack() is used for symmetry with pack() below
$firstaddrhex = reset(unpack('H*', $firstaddrbin));

// Overwriting first address string to make sure notation is optimal
$firstaddrstr = inet_ntop($firstaddrbin);

// Calculate the number of 'flexible' bits
$flexbits = 128 - $prefixlen;

// Build the hexadecimal string of the last address
$lastaddrhex = $firstaddrhex;

// We start at the end of the string (which is always 32 characters long)
$pos = 31;
while ($flexbits > 0) {
  // Get the character at this position
  $orig = substr($lastaddrhex, $pos, 1);

  // Convert it to an integer
  $origval = hexdec($orig);

  // OR it with (2^flexbits)-1, with flexbits limited to 4 at a time
  $newval = $origval | (pow(2, min(4, $flexbits)) - 1);

  // Convert it back to a hexadecimal character
  $new = dechex($newval);

  // And put that character back in the string
  $lastaddrhex = substr_replace($lastaddrhex, $new, $pos, 1);

  // We processed one nibble, move to previous position
  $flexbits -= 4;
  $pos -= 1;
}

// Convert the hexadecimal string to a binary string
# Using pack() here
# Newer PHP version can use hex2bin()
$lastaddrbin = pack('H*', $lastaddrhex);

// And create an IPv6 address from the binary string
$lastaddrstr = inet_ntop($lastaddrbin);

// Report to user
echo "Prefix: $prefix\n";
echo "First: $firstaddrstr\n";
echo "Last: $lastaddrstr\n";

?>
```

It should output:

```
Prefix: 2001:db8:abc:1400::/54
First: 2001:db8:abc:1400::
Last: 2001:db8:abc:17ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Comment: Exactly What I needed!!. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for days and I am currently in a cisco course but we haven't reached ipv6 yet so trying to grasp the concept on my own. I have been looking at the code, how much of a code change would need to be done if I also wanted the 2nd IP and the IP just before the last one? I have been trying to figure it out but out of my scope of php knowledge :(

Comment: Well, the second address has a 1 instead of 0 as the last character, and the second to last has an e instead of an f.

Comment: Sorry it has been a very busy few days and I was trying to get a an answer for the second IP and second to last lol... Still learning ipv6 but definitely learned a lot from your comments. Thank you again! and sorry for the delay in my replies.

Comment: You're welcome! Let me know if I can help! IPv6 stuff is my full-time occupation these days :-)

Comment: Actually your code works exactly the way I needed :). The changes I was looking for was due to my lack of knowledge :). Thanks again!

Comment: Please note that the first address in the block (i.e. 2001:db8:abc:1400:: with mask /64) is an anycast address that is automatically answered by all routers on the network. Do not assign this address to any host. All other addresses are usable.

Comment: For information, I saw that your answer has contributed to PhpMyAdmin code ;) https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/cf2de639f7f9e3cfca6c4a7262f717353afde130/libraries/ip_allow_deny.lib.php#L158

Comment: For the record, IPv6 address DOES have network address in it - the first 3 groups (or 48 bits) of it.

Comment: @durrrr In IPv4 the first address in a subnet was called the network address and unusable for hosts. That does not exist in IPv6. The first address is however reserved as anycast address for the default gateway. PS: Not all end-users get a /48 so you cannot rely on all addresses in a /48 belonging together either.

Comment: I actually just wanted to point out that this might not be the best way of saying it. That IPv6 doesn't have a network address. Because there is 3 blocks reserved for network (network address), one for subnet (subnet address) and last 4 for users' devices. That makes more sense, to me at least :)

Comment: That is a common way of address planning, but it doesn't have to be. A home user might only get a /56 (3.5 'block') which leaves only 8 bits (0.5 'block') for subnetting.

Comment: for this `$firstaddrhex = reset(unpack('H*', $firstaddrbin));` will create php7 notice , so u need to change to 2 lines. `unpack_value = unpack('H*', $firstaddrbin); $firstaddrhex = reset($unpack_value)`

Answer (score 7):

This is a fix to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086404/7560156), which incorrectly assumes the "first address" should be identical to the inputted string. Rather, it needs to have its value [modified via an `AND` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Subnetting) against its mask.

To demonstrate the problem, consider this example input: `2001:db8:abc:1403::/54`

[Expected result:](https://www.vultr.com/resources/subnet-calculator-ipv6/?prefix_length=1&display=long&ipv6_address=2001%3Adb8%3Aabc%3A1403%3A%3A%2F54)

```
First: 2001:db8:abc:1400::
```

Actual result:

```
First: 2001:db8:abc:1403::
```

The relevant math to calculate the mask for a given 4-bit sequence is:

```
// Calculate the subnet mask. min() prevents the comparison from being negative
$mask = 0xf << (min(4, $flexbits));

// AND the original against its mask
$newval = $origval & $mask;
```

#### Full code

```php
<?php

/*
 * This is definitely not the fastest way to do it!
 */

// An example prefix
$prefix = '2001:db8:abc:1403::/54';

// Split in address and prefix length
list($addr_given_str, $prefixlen) = explode('/', $prefix);

// Parse the address into a binary string
$addr_given_bin = inet_pton($addr_given_str);

// Convert the binary string to a string with hexadecimal characters
$addr_given_hex = bin2hex($addr_given_bin);

// Overwriting first address string to make sure notation is optimal
$addr_given_str = inet_ntop($addr_given_bin);

// Calculate the number of 'flexible' bits
$flexbits = 128 - $prefixlen;

// Build the hexadecimal strings of the first and last addresses
$addr_hex_first = $addr_given_hex;
$addr_hex_last = $addr_given_hex;

// We start at the end of the string (which is always 32 characters long)
$pos = 31;
while ($flexbits > 0) {
    // Get the characters at this position
    $orig_first = substr($addr_hex_first, $pos, 1);
    $orig_last = substr($addr_hex_last, $pos, 1);

    // Convert them to an integer
    $origval_first = hexdec($orig_first);
    $origval_last = hexdec($orig_last);

    // First address: calculate the subnet mask. min() prevents the comparison from being negative
    $mask = 0xf << (min(4, $flexbits));

    // AND the original against its mask
    $new_val_first = $origval_first & $mask;

    // Last address: OR it with (2^flexbits)-1, with flexbits limited to 4 at a time
    $new_val_last = $origval_last | (pow(2, min(4, $flexbits)) - 1);

    // Convert them back to hexadecimal characters
    $new_first = dechex($new_val_first);
    $new_last = dechex($new_val_last);

    // And put those character back in their strings
    $addr_hex_first = substr_replace($addr_hex_first, $new_first, $pos, 1);
    $addr_hex_last = substr_replace($addr_hex_last, $new_last, $pos, 1);

    // We processed one nibble, move to previous position
    $flexbits -= 4;
    $pos -= 1;
}

// Convert the hexadecimal strings to a binary string
$addr_bin_first = hex2bin($addr_hex_first);
$addr_bin_last = hex2bin($addr_hex_last);

// And create an IPv6 address from the binary string
$addr_str_first = inet_ntop($addr_bin_first);
$addr_str_last = inet_ntop($addr_bin_last);

// Report to user
echo "Prefix: $prefix\n";
echo "First: $addr_str_first\n";
echo "Last: $addr_str_last\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Prefix: 2001:db8:abc:1403::/54
First: 2001:db8:abc:1400::
Last: 2001:db8:abc:17ff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who stumble upon this question, you can do this more effectively using the [`dtr_pton`](http://mikemackintosh.github.com/dTR-IP/) and [`dtr_ntop`](http://mikemackintosh.github.com/dTR-IP/) functions and [`dTRIP`](http://mikemackintosh.github.com/dTR-IP/) class found on [GitHub](http://mikemackintosh.github.com/dTR-IP/).

We also have noticed a lack of focus and tools with IPv6 in PHP, and put together this article, http://www.highonphp.com/5-tips-for-working-with-ipv6-in-php, which may be of help to others.

**Function Source**

This converts and IP to a binary representation:

```
/**
 * dtr_pton
 *
 * Converts a printable IP into an unpacked binary string
 *
 * @author Mike Mackintosh - mike@bakeryphp.com
 * @param string $ip
 * @return string $bin
 */
function dtr_pton( $ip ){

    if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)){
        return current( unpack( "A4", inet_pton( $ip ) ) );
    }
    elseif(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)){
        return current( unpack( "A16", inet_pton( $ip ) ) );
    }

    throw new \Exception("Please supply a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address");

    return false;
}
```

This converts a binary representation to printable IP:

```
/**
 * dtr_ntop
 *
 * Converts an unpacked binary string into a printable IP
 *
 * @author Mike Mackintosh - mike@bakeryphp.com
 * @param string $str
 * @return string $ip
 */
function dtr_ntop( $str ){
    if( strlen( $str ) == 16 OR strlen( $str ) == 4 ){
        return inet_ntop( pack( "A".strlen( $str ) , $str ) );
    }

    throw new \Exception( "Please provide a 4 or 16 byte string" );

    return false;
}
```

**Examples**

Using the `dtr_pton` function you can:

```
$ip = dtr_pton("fe80:1:2:3:a:bad:1dea:dad");
$mask = dtr_pton("ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:fff0::");
```

Get your Network and Broadcast:

```
var_dump( dtr_ntop( $ip & $mask ) );
var_dump( dtr_ntop( $ip | ~ $mask ) );
```

And your output would be:

```
string(18) "fe80:1:2:3:a:ba0::"
string(26) "fe80:1:2:3:a:baf:ffff:ffff"
```

Comment: IPv6 does not support broadcast, there is thus no concept of a broadcast address.

Comment: @Steve-o Exactly, but since the term broadcast has been used in networking for a very long time, when emphasizing a range in IPv6, it is easier for people to understand. This is similar to the subnet segment, but many networks extend far past this segment..

Comment: The link to the blog post is dead. Can you please update or remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for posterity, I'm adding my `code` here. And also as a thanks to you guys who helped me nail this down as I needed it for an **ipv6/ip2country script**.

It's *slightly inspired* by code posted here by @**mikemacintosh** and @**Sander Steffann**, slightly improved *(whishful thinking)* and returns a nice object packing all the data you do/don't need:

```
/**
* This:
* <code>
* Ipv6_Prefix2Range('2001:43f8:10::/48');
* </code>
* returns this:
* <code>
* object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
*   ["Prefix"]=>
*   string(17) "2001:43f8:10::/48"
*   ["FirstHex"]=>
*   string(32) "200143f8001000000000000000000000"
*   ["LastHex"]=>
*   string(32) "200143f80010ffffffffffffffffffff"
*   ["MaskHex"]=>
*   string(32) "ffffffffffff00000000000000000000"
*   // Optional bin equivalents available
* }
* </code>
* 
* Tested against:
* @link https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRange
* 
* @param string $a_Prefix
* @param bool $a_WantBins
* @return object
*/
function Ipv6_Prefix2Range($a_Prefix, $a_WantBins = false){
    // Validate input superficially with a RegExp and split accordingly
    if(!preg_match('~^([0-9a-f:]+)[[:punct:]]([0-9]+)$~i', trim($a_Prefix), $v_Slices)){
        return false;
    }
    // Make sure we have a valid ipv6 address
    if(!filter_var($v_FirstAddress = $v_Slices[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)){
        return false;
    }
    // The /## end of the range
    $v_PrefixLength = intval($v_Slices[2]);
    if($v_PrefixLength > 128){
        return false; // kind'a stupid :)
    }
    $v_SuffixLength = 128 - $v_PrefixLength;

    // Convert the binary string to a hexadecimal string
    $v_FirstAddressBin = inet_pton($v_FirstAddress);
    $v_FirstAddressHex = bin2hex($v_FirstAddressBin);

    // Build the hexadecimal string of the network mask
    // (if the manually formed binary is too large, base_convert() chokes on it... so we split it up)
    $v_NetworkMaskHex = str_repeat('1', $v_PrefixLength) . str_repeat('0', $v_SuffixLength);
    $v_NetworkMaskHex_parts = str_split($v_NetworkMaskHex, 8);
    foreach($v_NetworkMaskHex_parts as &$v_NetworkMaskHex_part){
        $v_NetworkMaskHex_part = base_convert($v_NetworkMaskHex_part, 2, 16);
        $v_NetworkMaskHex_part = str_pad($v_NetworkMaskHex_part, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    $v_NetworkMaskHex = implode(null, $v_NetworkMaskHex_parts);
    unset($v_NetworkMaskHex_part, $v_NetworkMaskHex_parts);
    $v_NetworkMaskBin = inet_pton(implode(':', str_split($v_NetworkMaskHex, 4)));

    // We have the network mask so we also apply it to First Address
    $v_FirstAddressBin &= $v_NetworkMaskBin;
    $v_FirstAddressHex = bin2hex($v_FirstAddressBin);

    // Convert the last address in hexadecimal
    $v_LastAddressBin = $v_FirstAddressBin | ~$v_NetworkMaskBin;
    $v_LastAddressHex =  bin2hex($v_LastAddressBin);

    // Return a neat object with information
    $v_Return = array(
        'Prefix'    => "{$v_FirstAddress}/{$v_PrefixLength}",
        'FirstHex'  => $v_FirstAddressHex,
        'LastHex'   => $v_LastAddressHex,
        'MaskHex'   => $v_NetworkMaskHex,
    );
    // Bins are optional...
    if($a_WantBins){
        $v_Return = array_merge($v_Return, array(
            'FirstBin'  => $v_FirstAddressBin,
            'LastBin'   => $v_LastAddressBin,
            'MaskBin'   => $v_NetworkMaskBin,
        ));
    }
    return (object)$v_Return;
}
```

I like functions and classes and dislike non-reusable code where reusable functionality is implemented.

**PS**: *If you find issues with it, please get back to me. I'm far from an expert in IPv6.*

Comment: This is the perfect one which is matching with below urls conversion http://www.gestioip.net/cgi-bin/subnet_calculator.cgi

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static function rangeToCIDRv6($startIP, $endIP) {
        //转换成bin字符串格式
        $startBinary = inet_pton($startIP);
        $startBin = '';
        $bits = 15;
        while($bits >= 0) {
            $bin = sprintf("%08b",(ord($startBinary[$bits])));
            $startBin = $bin.$startBin;
            $bits--;
        }

        $endBinary = inet_pton($endIP);
        $endBin = '';
        $bits = 15;
        while($bits >= 0) {
            $bin = sprintf("%08b",(ord($endBinary[$bits])));
            $endBin = $bin.$endBin;
            $bits--;
        }

        //按位查询
        $cidrArray = array();
        $mask = 127;
        $diffFirst = false;
        while($mask>0){
            //位数不同
            if($startBin[$mask]!=$endBin[$mask]){
                while($startBin[$mask]!=$endBin[$mask]){
                    if($diffFirst){
                        $ipBin = str_pad(substr($startBin, 0, $mask).'1', 128, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                        $ip = '';
                        $Offset = 0;
                        while ($Offset <= 7) {
                            $bin_part = substr($ipBin, ($Offset*16), 16);
                            $ip .= dechex(bindec($bin_part));
                            if($Offset !=7){
                                $ip .= ":";
                            }
                            $Offset++;
                        }
                        $cidrArray[] = inet_ntop(inet_pton($ip)).'/'.($mask+1);
                    }
                    $mask--;
                }
                //首次不同
                if($diffFirst==false){
                    $diffFirst = true;

                    $ipBin = str_pad(substr($startBin, 0, $mask).'1', 128, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
                    $ip = '';
                    $Offset = 0;
                    while ($Offset <= 7) {
                        $bin_part = substr($ipBin, ($Offset*16), 16);
                        $ip .= dechex(bindec($bin_part));
                        if($Offset !=7){
                            $ip .= ":";
                        }
                        $Offset++;
                    }
                    $cidrArray[] = inet_ntop(inet_pton($ip)).'/'.($mask+1);
                }
            }else{
                $mask--;
            }
        }
        return $cidrArray;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).