# Proper way to find IPv6 in CIDR Range MySQL

Tags: mysql, bit-manipulation, ipv6

I have a MySQL blacklist table, with either single IPv4, IPv6 or CIDR ranges of one of both types stored in it.

My table looks *somewhat* like this:

```
 +-----------+-------------+
 | Name      | Type        |
 +-----------+-------------+
 | IpAddress | VARCHAR(46) |
 +-----------+-------------+
 | Mask      | INT(2)      |
 +-----------+-------------+
```

Now, I'd like to check whether a given IP address is in one of the saved CIDR ranges.
I already accomplished this after a few days of researching a whole lot of pages, and finally just ported the following solution to MySQL: [PHP5 calculate IPv6 range from cidr prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085266/php5-calculate-ipv6-range-from-cidr-prefix)

So I transform a IP + CIDR mask to the first and last IP in that range, which I then convert to numbers using INET6_ATON and compare it with the BETWEEN operator.

My implementation:

**Get last ip**

```mysql
FUNCTION (`Ip` VARCHAR(46), `Mask` INT(2) UNSIGNED) RETURNS varchar(39)
BEGIN
    DECLARE IpNumber VARBINARY(16);
    DECLARE Last VARCHAR(39) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE FlexBits, Counter, Deci, NewByte INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE HexIp VARCHAR(32);

    SET IpNumber = INET6_ATON(Ip);
    SET HexIp    = HEX(IpNumber);
    SET FlexBits = 128 - Mask;
    SET Counter  = 32;

    WHILE (FlexBits > 0) DO
        SET Deci    = CONV(SUBSTR(HexIp, Counter, 1), 16, 10);
        SET NewByte = Deci | (POW(2, LEAST(4, FlexBits)) - 1);
        SET Last    = CONCAT(CONV(NewByte, 10, 16), Last);

        IF FlexBits >= 4 THEN SET FlexBits = FlexBits - 4;
        ELSE SET FlexBits = 0;
        END IF;

        SET Counter  = Counter - 1;
    END WHILE;

    SET Last = CONCAT(SUBSTR(HexIp, 1, Counter), Last);

    RETURN INET6_NTOA(UNHEX(Last));
END
```

**Get first ip**

```mysql
FUNCTION (`Ip` VARCHAR(46), `Mask` INT(2) UNSIGNED, `WithMask` BOOLEAN) RETURNS varchar(39)
BEGIN
    DECLARE First VARCHAR (42) DEFAULT '';

    SET First = INET6_NTOA(UNHEX(RPAD(SUBSTR(HEX(INET6_ATON(Ip)), 1, Mask / 4), 32, 0)));

    IF (WithMask = 1) THEN
        SET First = CONCAT(First, '/', CAST(Mask AS CHAR));
    END IF;

    RETURN First;
END
```

This works fine! I just have the idea that it could be done way more efficient using some clever bit operations.
I've read tons of questions about this topic, but I didn't really found a concrete solution
Any help in the right direction would be really appreciated!

**NOTE**: Only for IPv6, I've got IPv4 implemented the correct way.

Comment: I know this is very old but has MYSQL changed the way it does FUNCTIONS?  5.6 won't accept this at all.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this for MySQL the same way about a year ago. So the idea is fine. However there's a small but rather significant bug in your code.

The line:

> SET Last    = CONCAT(Last, CONV(NewByte, 10, 16));

should rather be:

> SET Last    = CONCAT(CONV(NewByte, 10, 16), Last);

Comment: Well seen, thanks! That could've caused a real facepalm moment somewhere in the future. Although it doesn't really matter for most of the IP's you put in.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug in your **Get last ip** function.

instead of this:

```
SET FlexBits = FlexBits - 4;
```

use this:

```
IF FlexBits >= 4 THEN SET FlexBits = FlexBits - 4;
ELSE SET FlexBits = 0;
END IF;
```

---

Otherwise you will get this kind of error message:

```
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(FlexBits@4 - 4)'
```

When you try to get the last IP of these IPv6 ranges (where the mask cannot be divided by 4):

```
SELECT getLastIp("2001:200:1::", 47);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:200:0:8000", 49);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:470:1f06:2000::", 51);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:470:0:284:2::", 79);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:470:1f08:415::8:0", 109);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:550:0:1000::8275:8000", 113);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:550:0:1000::9a19:300", 123);
SELECT getLastIp("2001:550:0:1000::9a19:320", 126);
```