# Getting number of IPv6 addresses from Ipv6 CIDR in PHP

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, ipv6, cidr

**Is there a way to get the number of IPv6 addresses from a Ipv6 CIDR?**

for example: CIDR: 2403:3E00::/32 
=> 
need get number of ipv6 addresses: 79228162514264337593543950336

Comment: Is it possible to add in the function on that page (PHP5 calculate IPv6 range from cidr prefix) -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085266/php5-calculate-ipv6-range-from-cidr-prefix/10086404#10086404

that it additional return number of ip addresses in CIDR

Prefix: ...
First: ...
Last: ..
and
NumberIP: ... ?

Answer (score 0):

An IPv6 address has 128 bits, of which (slightly simplified) a number are dedicated to network address, and the rest are dedicated to host addresses.

In your case, 32 bits are dedicated to the network part (`/32`), so the other 96 are dedicated to host addresses.

```
2^(128-32) = 2^96 = 79228162514264337593543950336 hosts
```

Comment: To maintain precision you can use bcpow for this `echo bcpow(2, 128-32), "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

```
2^(128-32) = 2^96 = 79228162514264337593543950336
```

is wrong, you still need to

```
79228162514264337593543950336 - 1 = 79228162514264337593543950335 hosts
```

PS. sorry I could not comment it to the answer of Joachim because of reputation, this is why I am not much interested in stackoverflow.